# PHP - Possible to round a decimal to any specified decimal even 0.64 or 0.11

Tags: php, math, rounding

I have a number, lets say `45.67` and I need to round it to the nearest `.43`

eg. `45.67` rounds down to `45.43`.
Or if I have another number `34.98` and I need to round it to the nearest `.13`. It should round up to `35.13`.

Is this possible with PHP?

I have spent the good part of an afternoon trying to solve this, but any google search comes up with only being able to round to quarters as in .25 or halves .5. it looks as though it is not possible. AI GPT or Bard cannot solve it either.

Comment: Sure, with simple math and comparisons. But it's not something out of the box

Comment: Use `floor()` and `ceil()` to round it down and up. Add the fraction to each of those, and see which is closer to the original.

Comment: Rounding to fractions like this is an incredibly weird thing. What's the use case?

Comment: @barmar I'm adding a price change feature to an accounting package. Users can pick a percentage increase and a rounding decimal for adjustments. While I considered limiting it to multiples of 0.25, I aimed to accommodate all possibilities from 0.1 to 0.99. However, it seems this isn't achievable based on my observations.

Comment: Why isn't it achievable? I explained above how to implement it. There are other methods, like get the difference between the current fraction and the desired fraction. If it's more than .50 round up, if it's less then .50 round down.

Comment: @bamar I claim it's unattainable due to my inability, prompting my inquiry here. Could you provide an illustrative instance for better comprehension on my end?

Comment: @barmar & @aynber The solution turned out to be quite straightforward. There was no necessity for ceiling or flooring operations, and it seems that the functionality is readily available as a built-in feature `round($val - $frac) + $frac`

Comment: That's not a built-in, it's the "simple math" that aynber was talking about.

Comment: @barman Ah, I see! So it's not a hidden gem but rather the "simple math" wizardry in action. Well, hats off to aynber for unraveling the arithmetic enchantment!

Comment: @warmwhisky What is result is expected with `roundFrac(-45.67, 0.43);`?

Comment: @Reinstate Monica I'm not sure. My system will never allow a minus for the `$val` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
function roundFrac($val, $frac)
{
    return round($val - $frac) + $frac;
}

echo roundFrac(45.67, 0.43); // 45.43
echo roundFrac(34.98, 0.13); // 35.13
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir, this worked in all scenarios. I am surprised how simple this is!